# adMob not working on real device (iPhone)

Tags: ios, admob

I tested adMob with iOS simulator. It shows ads at the bottom of the screen.
But when I change it to real device the ads not showing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82pCX.png)

## AppDelegate.m

```
[GADMobileAds configureWithApplicationID:@"ca-app-pub-7067850045620785~8479598780"];
```

## ViewController.m

```
self.bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];

self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-7067850045620785/6404933932";
self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
[self.bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
self.bannerView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that once you've switched to a live device with a non-test adUnitId it can take roughly 30 minutes to build the inventory up to load.

I've experienced this before and found my answer here: [AdMob's Help](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2993019?hl=en)

If the test ad is working, give it some time.

And, obviously, make sure you have access to the internet.

Comment: You can also add you device Id to the list of test device when you initialise the bannerview in order to be served test ads on that device

Comment: @Paulw11 - I always just gave the bannerAd the test ID supplied by AdMob per their instructions:  [AdMob Quick-Start](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start).  From AdMob:  _The easiest way to load test ads is to use our dedicated test ad unit ID for iOS banners: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716._

Comment: Thank you guys, It really works after 20~30mins from the device change without change any source code. :)