# adMob not working with test ad on real device

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have added code to add admob in my app.The test adunit gives test ad on simulator but not on a real device.Although I have added my device id in the test devices.
I found an answer to this on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48392112/admob-not-working-on-real-device-iphone) but it is about the real ad not showing. But in my case it is also not showing the test ads.
Here is my code which I am using.

```
bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(bannerView)
    view.addConstraints(
        [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                            attribute: .bottom,
                            relatedBy: .equal,
                            toItem: bottomLayoutGuide,
                            attribute: .top,
                            multiplier: 1,
                            constant: 0),
         NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                            attribute: .centerX,
                            relatedBy: .equal,
                            toItem: view,
                            attribute: .centerX,
                            multiplier: 1,
                            constant: 0)
        ])
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
    let requestAd:GADRequest = GADRequest()
    requestAd.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID, "b8e41041fae0a22d8d95ff6b9c0e003a"]
    bannerView.load(requestAd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

1. Product
2. Scheme
3. Arguments
4. Environment Variables

There is a setting called `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE`. You must remove or disable that key.